# Can't reverse DNS lookup with BIND9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm creating an local network bind server.

I wrote this config file

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
acl localnet {
  192.168.1.0/24;
  127.0.0.0/8;
};
zone "example.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.local";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192.168.1";
};
```

/etc/bind/db.example.local

```
$TTL            3600
@       IN SOA  ns.example.local. dns01.example.local. (
                2007112701;     Serial
                3600;         Refresh
                86400;          Retry
                2419200;        Expire
                3600 );       Negative Cache TTL
;
                IN NS   ns.example.local
        IN MX   10  mail01.example.local
@       IN A    192.168.1.108
dns01           IN A    192.168.1.108
ns              IN CNAME dns01
gateway         IN A    192.168.1.1
```

/etc/bind/db.192.168.1

```
$TTL    3600
@       IN SOA  ns.example.local. dns01.example.local. (
                2007112702;     Serial
                3600;         Refresh
                86400;          Retry
                2419200;        Expire
                3600 );       Negative Cache TTL
;
    IN  NS      ns.example.local.
200 IN  PTR dns01.example.local.
1   IN  PTR gateway.example.local.
```

and then /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
and /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain example.local
nameserver 192.168.1.108



$ nslookup dns01
Server:         192.168.1.108
Address:        192.168.1.108#53

Name:   dns01.example.local
Address: 192.168.1.108
$ nslookup dns01
Server:         192.168.1.108
Address:        192.168.1.108#53

Name:   dns01.example.local
Address: 192.168.1.108

$ nslookup 192.168.1.108                                                                                                                                                                    
Server:         192.168.1.108
Address:        192.168.1.108#53

** server can't find 108.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN [#id7e65d6]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @ffffff - Please thank theotherreceive by accepting their answer.  The ettiquite of this site is to accept the answer which helps you resolve your question.  You might like to revisit most of your other questions and accept the answer which helped you resolve that question.  I'm sure the person answering the question would appreciate the recognition for helping you.

Comment: -1 for not accepting the answer after 2 requests to do so and 4 years.

Answer (score 12):

Is that your full /etc/bind/db.192.168.1, cause it doesn't include an entry for 108.

```
$TTL    3600
1.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA       IN SOA  ns.example.local. dns01.example.local. (
                2007112702;     Serial
                3600;         Refresh
                86400;          Retry
                2419200;        Expire
                3600 );       Negative Cache TTL
    IN  NS      ns.example.local.

$ORIGIN 1.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.

108 IN  PTR     dns01.example.local.
1   IN  PTR     gateway.example.local.
```

Comment: oops! How to resolve?

Comment: It looks like you have an entry for dns01.zeg.local as 200, surely this should read 108?

Comment: Updated answer with suggested changes